# response.json() never completes

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I'm using fetch to make a request to an API. The result is supposed to be a JSON object with a Base64 string representing a PDF, of size roughly 150kb.

When I run this code, I'm running into a problem:

```
const result = await fetch('api-url.com/pdf');

try {
  const parsedResult = await result.json(); // This hangs, and never completes, nor throws
} catch (error) {
  // This is never reached either
}
```

The `result.json()` part never completes. I tried using `.text()`, `.blob()` with no success either (even though I'm certain the response type if application/json).

I really don't know what else I can try, especially since I ran the same request through Postman, and everything worked perfectly fine, I got the string out of it in the JSON object.

There is something specific to `fetch`, and `.json()` that is failing but I don't know what.

Comment: What do you see in developer console? What in network panel?

Comment: @RobertRowntree um, you need to await the fetch and you need to await the json call....

Comment: How exactly do you *know* that the `result.json()` call never returns?

Comment: @pointy I simply add 3 console.logs, before .json(), after .json(), and in the catch block